# iPhone: Get warning when battery power is very low

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I want to know how can i get warning in my app delegate when the device battery power is very low. So that i can pause the running game.

Any idea?

Comment: I think it's the job of Apple to do it for you. AFAIK, you cann't access it programmatically.

Comment: Apple gives me alert.....but after getting this type of alert i need to pause my game.....e.g: hot pursuit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the battery level property from `UIDevice`. If the battery level is less than 5% show an alert for example. You could poll periodically for the battery level in your app delegate for example.

```
UIDevice *myDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice]; 
[myDevice setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES]; 
float batteryLevel = [myDevice batteryLevel];
```

Explanation from [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/batteryLevel):

> **batteryLevel**
>   The battery charge level for the device. (read-only)
>
> `@property(nonatomic, readonly) float batteryLevel`
>
> **Discussion**
>   Battery level ranges from 0.0 (fully discharged) to 1.0
>   (100% charged). Before accessing this property, ensure that battery
>   monitoring is enabled.
>
> If battery monitoring is not enabled, battery state is
>   `UIDeviceBatteryStateUnknown` and the value of this property is –1.0.
>
> **Availability**
>   Available in iOS 3.0 and later.
>
> **See Also**
>     `@property batteryState`
>     `@property batteryMonitoringEnabled`
>
> **Declared In**
>   UIDevice.h

Comment: according to your code should i have to run a infinite schedule and always check the battery level??...i am actually expecting some delegate.....

Comment: i didn't see any protocol for this. but you can create an NSTimer with a good interval that will call a method that will update the value.if you see that the value goes below a critical level throw a notification. Your game could listen for that notification and pause the game...just an idea.

Comment: is that the only way? many game(e.g hot pursuit,ice age) pause the app when battery power is below 20%......are they check battery status all time and do it??

Comment: You don't need a timer, battery state and level are observable. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834506/detect-low-battery-warning-ios