# Is there any broadcast from ios for low battery as in case of android?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.ios, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I am an android developer working in Xamarin. I am relatively new to iOS.

I want to detect, from my app, when the battery becomes low.

In android I implemented using `BroadcastReceiver`.

Although in iOS I am unable to find a pub-sub model like that of android.

In iOS I want register a broadcast receiver for low battery broadcasts from the OS, so that I be notified in the app should the battery become low.

Even swift code is acceptable. I can make it work in Xamarin from there.

Below is my Xamarin code for android implementation.

```
    public class AppBatteryBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
            int level = intent.GetIntExtra(BatteryManager.ExtraLevel, -1);
            int scale = intent.GetIntExtra(BatteryManager.ExtraScale, -1);
            int levelPercentage = (level != -1 && scale != -1) ? (int)Math.Floor(level * 100D / scale) : 101; 

    }
}
```

I am registering an instance of this class from my MainActivity.cs like below

```
var intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.AddAction(Intent.ActionBatteryChanged);
        RegisterReceiver(_batteryBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

In android every time battery changes I get notified in the `OnReceive` method above. From there I can check if the battery is below a certain level.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834506/detect-low-battery-warning-ios

Comment: Have you implemented it with the link above?

Comment: Yes. It definitely guided me to the right direction.