# iOS low battery notification custom-calling

Tags: ios, notifications, batterylevel

I wonder, is it possible to call a custom window in my iOS application alike low-battery notification, to test the application behavior during notification shown

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14834620/7316675 might find help in here

Comment: When ever any system alert is shown your app will resign active with the appropriate app delegate function being called as well as the will resign active notification being posted

Comment: I dont follow. please provide more information