# low battery notification

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

i am a beginner in iOS programming. I was wondering if there is a way to make a app that fires a local notification when the battery reaches 20%. That is I launch the app and give the appropriate changes. After terminating or killing the app from the task manager it fires a local notification when the battery reaches 20%.

Comment: Have a look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677515/iphone-get-warning-when-battery-power-is-very-low

Comment: And here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834506/detect-low-battery-warning-ios please search before posting.

Comment: ok thank you and forgive me for my late reply

Comment: um.. i'm sorry but what i'm trying to do is different. i'm trying to do a battery monitoring app like battery doctor, where even if the app is not running and if my phone's battery level decreases to 20% it would give out a notification saying that the phone needs to be charged.